# asterisk conference calls

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, conference

I am working with ubuntu and asterisk 1.8. I've set the configuration for conference calls:

in extensions.conf

```
exten => 2115,1,Answer()
exten => 2115,n,Set(CHANNEL(language)=gb-f)
exten => 2115,n,Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=default)
exten => 2115,n,ConfBridge(1234,Mcs,123)
```

Is there an android application with whom to test this conference channel? I would like to test it between 3 sip clients. How to do this? Are my settings correct?

1234 is the conference room also set in Meetme.conf

THX appreciate

Comment: do you have 3 devices? than you can use SipDroid, CSIpSimple, IMSDroid. You can also use software clients - Ekiga etc.

Comment: can i test with imsdroid on all 3 devices? how to do tthat? i've made a simple call to 2115 with all 3 devices using imsdroid. the video stops. audio works. when client 3 ends the call both audio and video works.

Comment: if the video and audio works in some cases, that probably means your Asterisk configuration is OK, and you may have problems in your SDP offers. Also research the capabilities for video conferencing on Asteriks. I know the audio mixer should work, but I am not sure how it handles video conferencing. Make note of the video codecs you use on all devices...this could also be an issue.

Comment: the video codecs are ok. The sdp i guess it's correct bcause it's cone by ConfBridge. I don't understand why on ekiga there are no 2 other video windows with each device from the conference call. have any ideas?

Comment: nope sorry, my knowledge in conferencing extends to audio calls.

Comment: as i've seens the communications are  between the server and each client:) ...is it correct?

Comment: i didn't set 2115 in sip.conf. Do I have to set it there too?

Comment: yes - the communication is between the server and each client. In the case of conference-audio call, the audio mixer on the server mixes the rtp streams from all clients into 1 rtp stream and sends it to 1 client, and it does that for all clients.

Comment: no, you don't need 2115 into sip.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already say you here

**Asterisk support only ONE way video conference.**

If you are expecting get mixed conference stream, see vmuktu or other solution.

Comment: can you tell me how to install vmuktu on ubuntu and how to use it with asterisk?

Comment: I 've understood that asterisk is one way video conference, but when a 3 sip clients comes in the conference the video is freeze on all phones. No video at all. why?1

Comment: No. i can't "tell" you how to install vmuktu.Please consult project page. Metmee video work only if 1) all codecs SAME 2) only one set to "speeking" mode. all other is muted off.